# Problem with Classify Documentation Center page

Tags: bugs, documentation

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2**

---

Every time I try to open the "Neat Examples" tab on the documentation center page for the function `Classify` Mma gets stuck showing "Progress  Dialog". The problem persists after disabling dynamic evaluation.

Can someone confirm this problem?

OS: Linux
Mma ver: 10.0.1

Comment: I confirm (Linux and 10.0.1 also). My traffic monitor shows that Mma tries to download something.

Comment: OS X 10.9.5 yes it seems data is being downloaded when you try and open neat examples.

Comment: It seems the offending example has been deleted from the documentation in V10.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I confirm (Windows 7 x64, MMa 10.0.1). After opening the "Neat Examples" tab in the Documentation Center page for `Classify` MathKernel.exe loads HUGE amount of data from pacletserver2.wolfram.com. After 2 hours of waiting with hanging *Mathematica* FrontEnd I found in the

> %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Temporary

directory more than 600 files with names ranging from "Classifier_Language-1.0.09441.paclet" to "Classifier_Language-1.0.09441000.paclet" most of which have file size about 4.42 Mb. The overall size of the directory is now 2.48 Gb and keeps growing. The FrontEnd still does not respond.

### UPDATE

I have found that all the files grow only up to the size of 4643101 bytes and **are exactly identical** on this final stage (I have checked this with Windows' `fc /B` command-line tool)! Up to the moment I have already about 800 files and it looks like the process will not stop until all the 1000 identical files (names range from "Classifier_Language-1.0.0944**1**.paclet" to "Classifier_Language-1.0.0944**1000**.paclet") will be loaded from pacletserver2.wolfram.com. It is clearly a bug.

### UPDATE 2

After several hours of the above-described "work" Mathematica has crashed. The files in the folder are still here and were not deleted after restarting *Mathematica*. Their overall size is 3.44 Gb.

Comment: That's pretty neat :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with the very first demo under "Neat Examples":

```
DynamicModule[{text = ""}, 
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[text], String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
    FieldHint -> "Enter a string"], 
   Dynamic[Classify["Language", text, "TopProbabilities"]]}]]
```

I can reproduce the bug exactly when I evaluate this in v10.0.1 on OSX 10.9.5 (sorry, would have just added this as a comment but am very new here and can't comment yet). I've sent a bug report to Wolfram.

**Update.** I've heard back from Wolfram. As a temporary fix to avoid triggering the bug, the example can be evaluated properly by adding `Classify["Language", "”]` before evaluating the DynamicModule:

```
Classify["Language", ""];
DynamicModule[{text = "" }, 
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[text], String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
 FieldHint -> "Enter a string"],
Dynamic[Classify["Language", text, "TopProbabilities"]]}]]
```

The remaining "Neat Examples" demos in the [Classify](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) docs work without issue.

Comment: That bug persists in 10.1: Just try to evaluate `DynamicModule[{text = ""}, 
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[text], String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
    FieldHint -> "Enter a string"], 
   Dynamic[Classify["Language", text, "TopProbabilities"]]}]]` and find *Mathematica* downloading a file Classifier_Language-1.0.15184191.paclet into \AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Temporary on and on and on again...

Answer (score 1):

Observation in *Mathematica* 10.1:

**The problem persists** (in a way):

That bug persists in 10.1: Just try to evaluate the former "Neat Examples"-snippet (which is no longer in the documentation):

```
DynamicModule[{text = ""}, Column[{InputField[Dynamic[text], String,
  ContinuousAction -> True, FieldHint -> "Enter a string"],
  Dynamic[Classify["Language", text, "TopProbabilities"]]}]]
```

and find Mathematica downloading a file Classifier_Language-1.0.15184191.paclet into \AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Temporary\ on and on and on again, overwriting the previous copy.

Meanwhile, the frontend is absolutely non-responsive, so you eventually will have to kill *Mathematica*.