# Mathematica AppData folder is taking up too much space

Tags: curated-data, resource-management, storage

I recently made a [small app that I had issues with](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63771/is-450-lines-of-code-in-one-block-too-much). I'm pretty sure it ended up being because of all the curated data to load. My problem now is that under the Windows 8.1 folder Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Mathematica/Paclets/Temporary, there is 10GB of "GraphData" files. I have a small SSD and I need to get rid of this stuff. Now I'm assuming I can probably delete it, but I thought I'd ask if there's a proper way to delete this stuff (like a certain command or something). And finally, is there a way of preventing Mathematica from downloading so much data onto my computer, or at least deleting it once I'm done with it? That one day I loaded up my app, I lost 10 GB over the course of a couple hours.

The real question here is: why does Mathematica generate a rather large folder of data from the use of one notebook, and not clear it somehow afterwards? Is there a way of configuring how much temporary curated data is stored on your computer? Is there a way of clearing it without actually deleting the contents of the folder?

Comment: Are these in the `Paclets/Repository` directory or the `Paclets/Temporary` directory?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that. 9.3 GB are in the Paclets/Temporary folder, 400 MB in the Paclets/Repository folder.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, would it be safe to delete the contents of the `Paclets/Temporary` folder? I'm really running low on space and could really use that 10GB right about now. What about the `Paclets/Repository` as well?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot speak from experience.  I would *guess* that a the contents of a folder named `Temporary` could be deleted while the program is not running without being destructive however I can give you no assurance of that.  It is also unfortunate that your question has not attracted an answer yet.

Comment: To be honest I don't think it will get an answer. It's not so much "can I delete this folder", but more "why is Mathematica taking up so much space (10 GB) for *one* block of code that I made, and not deleting it when it's done?" I know it's all from the one notebook because every file in that folder starts with the word GraphData, which was what I was using in that notebook. I think I'll just shoot first and ask questions later.

Comment: For what it's worth that single up-vote is mine; I find it an interesting question though I haven't tried to explore it.  Really this kind of resource management should be transparent and user-configurable.

Comment: I think this thread is closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61333/280 From my experience, it is absolutely safe to delete the contents of the Temporary directory.

Comment: Tangentially related Wolfram Support article: "[How do I transfer paclet data to an offline computer?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12436)"

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party: I found this question today while testing out how to apply time constraints to functions accessing curated data ([How to set the timeout value for *Data functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85222/27951)).

In order to test a function accessing curated data, I had to clear the cached data on my computer, so I could reproduce the conditions of a first access and the accompanying long loading times. I was trying to figure out whether there is a nice programmatic way to flush local data for a particular repository. I couldn't find any, but I found this question.

In my case, the data was associated with `WeatherData` results, and it was residing in folders name WeatherData*, and CityData*. It had been generated from evaluation of the following expression:

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature", {1950, 1}]
```

Eventually, I just decided to test out what would happen if I simply deleted the data while *Mathematica* was running. For what it's worth, I'm on MMA v. 10.1 on Win7-64bit, also on an SSD.

The results were **very benign**:

- the WeatherData folders could be deleted just fine, but the CityData* folder could not, indicating to me that *Mathematica* had those files open at the time.
- I then `Quit[]` the kernel from the front end; I could then delete the remaining CityData* folders.
- Restarting the kernel and evaluating the same expression re-downloaded the data and re-generated the indices with no complaints.

Of course this is little more than a commentary to the OP's main question regarding **transparent management of downloaded data**. That part is still wide open, but I don't think that mere users can answer that one without insight from WRI...