# How to keep downloaded curated data

Tags: curated-data, resource-management, storage

If I run `StarData[]`, *Mathematica* will download the entire database from its server, which is quite a lot of data and takes some time:

> "Downloading entities 17501 through 20000 of 107522 ...."

Eventually it downloads everything and displays it as a list of entities. However, the next time I start the kernel and execute `StarData[]`, *Mathematica* will download the entire database again. This is a huge waste of resources. Is it possible to keep the downloaded curated data between *Mathematica* sessions?

Comment: Related: [64130](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64130/mathematica-appdata-folder-is-taking-up-too-much-space)

Comment: Also strongly related: [(3459)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3549/7167)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two types of curated data in the Wolfram Language, the classic "paclet" functions like `ChemicalData` and the `EntityValue` Knowledgebase functions like `StarData`, and only the former supports the "Preload" mechanism. If the first item in the ref 'details' section of the ref pages says `The specified "name" in XXXXData can be an Entity, EntityClass, or canonical name.` then the function is a Knowledgebase function.

You can always save the results of `StarData[]` with a function like `DumpSave` or `Save`, and simply `Get["file"]` in a future session, though I understand there are plans in the works for all Knowledgebase functions like `StarData` to have a caching mechanism in the future.

Answer (score 6):

In Mathematica 10.4.0 (February 26, 2016), `StarData[]` and similar, e.g. `MinorPlanetData[],` is now cached. It downloads only once, no matter whether Kernel is stopped or no. Partial download also is cached.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I can confirm it keeps the data between Mathematica sessions and kernel restarts.

Answer (score 2):

You used to be able to Preload paclet data

```
PacletName["All", "Preload"]
```

For e.g. chemical data you'd type:

```
ChemicalData["All", "Preload"]
```

See also this [support article](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12436)

I've heard rumors (but haven't tried it myself) that in v10 this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, for `StarData` I get `Missing["UnknownEntity", {"Star", "All"}]`. With `ChemicalData` it seems to download the data but the next time I start Mathematica it downloads it again. v10.0.2

Comment: In 10.1, only the index is downloaded and installed into Paclets\Repository. The data itself remains remote until accessed explicitly.

Comment: @shrx is this on your RPi?  can preload (e.g) ElementData on 10.0.2 Windows but it appears to ignore preloading on the RPi for me.

Comment: @bobthechemist no, this was on my Linux machine at work.