# Downloading curated data

Tags: curated-data

[This website](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12436) shows how to download curated data for offline usage. I thought I could do this on a computer connected to internet as well as a means of caching the data so that I do not have to download it all the time.
So I did:

```
MinorPlanetData[All, "Preload"]
MinorPlanetData[All, "Install"]
```

but the result was:
[image: Curated data problem]

So I found this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78954/how-to-keep-downloaded-curated-data). While the answer suggests how to save individual entities produced by `MinorPlanetData[]`, I am more interested in saving the data themselves. e.g. I need `minors = MinorPlanetData[]; MinorPlanetData[minors, "Eccentricity"];` this is not doable with the ridiculous connection that the Wolfram servers have (it is funny as the download gets slower as it progresses, when Mathematica says "Downloading 18440 of 39001 values." the speed is about 1 value per second and getting slower).

Also the answer mentioned above is mostly on v 10. Has anyone figured out how to save the data locally (on v11)?