# How to set the timeout value for *Data functions

Tags: curated-data, system-variables, entity

I haven't measured this precisely but it seems the default timeout value for retrieving `EntityValue`s with `*Data` functions is in the range of tens of seconds. This significantly impacts the execution time if the `*Data` function is called repeatedly, because I often get an

```
 EntityValue::timeout: A network operation for EntityValue timed out. Please try again later. >>
```

error.

Is it possible to manually set the timeout value for such functions that retrieve curated data from Wolfram servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the call to the *Data function in `TimeConstrained`. This function will evaluate its argument for the maximum number of seconds specified. If the computation has not completed in that time, it will return `$Aborted`. Of course, you will probably have to manage the aborted computation somehow, but from my reading of your question that doesn't seem to be a problem.

For instance:

```
TimeConstrained[WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature", {1950, 1}], 0.1]
```

returns `$Aborted` on my system; if I use a more lax time constrain, e.g. 1 s, I obtain my result.

This problem is particularly relevant for data that need download and initialization of a local archive / index when first accessed, such as the `WeatherData` results above. The `TimeConstrained` function will stop the loading of the database as well as the data processing in that case.

As an aside, the database loading is incremental in those cases: if you execute the same time-limited expression enough times, it will download and process a small chunk each time, until at the end it will have downloaded everything it needs and will be able to answer from local data, which will be very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will test it later. And I can add another `While[output === $Aborted, repeat]` to deal with timeouts.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the network timeout for WolframAlpha calls by using:

```
SetOptions[WolframAlpha, TimeConstraint -> 300]
```

for example.

Comment: Does it work with `*Data` functions? Can't check right now.

Comment: Works for me with the AirportData function.

Comment: I can't find this in the Preferences GUI anywhere (10.1). Does anyone know if it's there? If not, I can imagine plenty of users wanting access to it in the frontend.