# List of all dog breeds

Tags: curated-data, entity

How to make  a list of  all dog breeds with pictures and names

like this

[image]

I tried:

```
EntityValue[
Take[EntityList[EntityClass["DogBreed", All]], 3], "Image"]
```

but there is an error message

[image]

Comment: The error is saying that the network call to Wolfram's servers timed-out. Check your internet connection and try again.

Comment: @Edmund I checked, there is no problem about internet connection

Comment: The code works for me in version 10.3 of Mma. It is a network error. Have you tried again since? If so and it still is not working then perhaps someone else will have an idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)"  *)

Grid[
 Partition[
  Column[#, Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All] & /@
   EntityValue[
    Take[
     EntityList[EntityClass["DogBreed", All]],
     9],
    {"Name", "Image"}],
  3],
 Alignment -> Top]
```

[image]

EDIT: To show all, pull a "page" at a time.

```
imagesPerPage = 15;

total = EntityList[EntityClass["DogBreed", All]] // Length

(*  376  *)

pages = Ceiling[total/imagesPerPage]

(*  26  *)

Table[
  Grid[
   Partition[
    Column[#, Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All] & /@
     EntityValue[
      Take[
       EntityList[EntityClass["DogBreed", All]],
       (n - 1)*imagesPerPage + 1 ;; Min[n*imagesPerPage, total]],
      {"Name", "Image"}],
    3, 3, {1, 1}, ""],
   Alignment -> Top],
  {n, pages}] // Column
```

Comment: it works, but if I put in "All" instead "9", there is a same problem. I think this is [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85222/how-to-set-the-timeout-value-for-data-functions)